# Multiple similar SELECTs in one statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union

I have these SELECT statements in SQL:
this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    products
WHERE
    product_category = '12'
LIMIT
    3
```

and this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    products
WHERE
    product_category = '36'
LIMIT
    3
```

and this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    products
WHERE
    product_id IN ('3178','3181','7403')
LIMIT
    3
```

As you can see they are very similar, what I want is to run these 3 statement effectively, point of that is that whole result should be 9 rows long (because 3x3), and firstly should be displayed three products from category 12, then second three products should be displayed from category 36 and the last three products should be products with IDs 3178,3181,7403.

**I know** that I can use `UNION` like this:

```
    (SELECT
        *
    FROM
        products
    WHERE
        product_category = '12'
    LIMIT
        3)
UNION
    (SELECT
        *
    FROM
        products
    WHERE
        product_category = '36'
    LIMIT
        3)
UNION
    (SELECT
        *
    FROM
        products
    WHERE
        product_id IN ('3178','3181','7403')
    LIMIT
        3)
LIMIT 9
```

But I wonder, if there is more effective way, because these statements are mostly copies.

Comment: why you are limiting to 3? Any specific reason?

Comment: Note that `UNION` alone will not guarantee your required order of category=12, then 36 and so on.. "*UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows*" . Refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html

Comment: which MySQL version you are using?

Comment: @James because it must be 3

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8+, you can use window functions:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM (SELECT p.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_category, 
                                             product_id IN (3178, 3181, 7403)
                                ORDER BY product_category
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM products p
      WHERE product_category IN (12, 36) OR
            product_id IN (3178, 3181, 7403)
     ) p
WHERE seqnum <= 3
ORDER BY (product_category = 12) DESC,
         (product_category = 36) DESC;
```

Comment: This will not ensure the OP's requirement of: "*firstly should be displayed three products from category 12, then second three products should be displayed from category 36 and the last three products should be products with IDs 3178,3181,7403.*"  .. **btw not my DV**

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya . . . That is because the `UNION` query doesn't do this and the OP claims that the `UNION` works.  But I added the appropriate `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Can you help me, on the 3rd line `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_category,` I get error that missing closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

for mysql version 8.0 or greater and you can reduce one subquery

```
select col1,col2,col3 from (SELECT *, row_number() over(partition by product_category  order by product_category) rn
    FROM
        products
    WHERE
        product_category in( 12,36) 
) a where a.rn<=3


union 
  SELECT
        col1,col2,col3
    FROM
        products
    WHERE
        product_id IN ('3178','3181','7403') order by product_id
    LIMIT
        3
```

Comment: This will not ensure the OP's requirement of: "*firstly should be displayed three products from category 12, then second three products should be displayed from category 36 and the last three products should be products with IDs 3178,3181,7403.*"  .. **btw not my DV**

Answer (score 0):

```
UNION ALL
```

UNION alone will try to merge similar records as one.  With UNION ALL, will show everything.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps if you really want to make this more efficient you have to look at it a slightly different way and not limit yourself to the query, but think about updating your database structure.

For example, you could add a new column in `products` table to handle the group order.

```
| product_id | product_category | product_group |
|------------|------------------|---------------|
| 3178       |                  | c             |
|            | 12               | a             |
|            | 36               | b             |
| 3181       |                  | c             |
| 7403       |                  | c             |
```

And get the result with a simple query :

```
SELECT * from products
WHERE product_group in (a, b, c)
ORDER BY product_group
```

Depending on why you're limiting to just 3 results per group, it probably makes more sense anyway to use code to manage which of the entries you want to return (so having some code to set the `product_group` field), not simply the 3 first entries from your table, in no specific order.

Comment: @James beg to differ, as the OP's question is "I wonder, if there is more effective way". But point taken, in that it is an indirect answer.